# How to use jQuery $.extend(obj1, obj2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, extends

I'm trying to create a button class that extends an AbstractComponent class using $.extend() but the functions in AbstractComponent aren't available when I'm constructing the button.

The specific error I'm receiving is:
 Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'setOptions'

```
var Button = {};
var abstract = new AbstractComponent;
$.extend(Button,abstract);
//debugger;
//this.setOptions is available here
Button = function(options) {
    'use strict';
    var defaultOptions = {
        templateName: '#button-tmpl',
        title: "Label goes here",
        type: "primary",
        size: "medium",
        disabled: null,
        autosave: null,
        href: null,
        onclick: null
    };
//debugger
//this.setOptions is not available here
    this.setOptions(options, defaultOptions);
    this.checkRequiredKeys('title');
    return this;
};
Button.prototype.updateOptions = function() {
    var options = this.options;
    if (options.href === null) {
        options.href = 'javascript:;';
    }
    if (options.disabled === null) {
        options.disabled = 'disabled';
    }
    if (options.autosave === true) {
        options.autosave = 'ping-autosave';
    }
};
```

AbstractComponent.js

```
var AbstractComponent = function() {
    console.log('this will be the constructor for elements extending this class');
};
AbstractComponent.prototype.show = function() {
    this.render();
};
AbstractComponent.prototype.close = function() {
    // stop listeners and remove this component
    this.stopListening();
    this.remove();
};
AbstractComponent.prototype.getTemplateName = function() {
    return this.options.templateName;
};    
AbstractComponent.prototype.checkRequiredKeys = function() {
    var errors = new Array();
    if (typeof this.getTemplateName() === "undefined") {
        errors.push('templateName');
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (!this.options.hasOwnProperty(arguments[i])) {
            errors.push(arguments[i]);
        }
    }
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        throw new Exception("Required property(s) not found:" + errors.join(', ') + " in " + this.toString());
    }
};

AbstractComponent.prototype.getElement = function() {
    'use strict';
    if(!this.options.updated) {
        this.updateOptions();
    }
    return new AbstractView(this.options).render().$el;
};


AbstractComponent.prototype.updateOptions = function() {
    this.options.updated = true;
    return true;
};

AbstractComponent.prototype.getHtml = function() {
    return this.getElement().html();
};

AbstractComponent.prototype.setOptions = function(options, defaultOptions) {
    this.options = _.defaults(options, defaultOptions);
};

AbstractComponent.prototype.toString = function() {
    return "Component" + this.getTemplateName() + "[id=" + this.options.id + "]";
};
```

Comment: that's not the intended purpose of the $.extend method. It's for plain objects only.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for doing what I'm trying to do there?

Comment: Not really, but i do see a logic error in the beginning. First, you defined `Button` as an object. Next, you extended it with `abstract`, **then you set `Button` equal to a function, thus overwriting everything you did to `Button` in the beginning.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery extend is for moving properties from one (or more) object(s) to another object.

```
$.extend({}, {
   foo: 10,
   bar: 20
});
```

You should use prototypal inheritance isntead

```
function Button(options) {
    'use strict';
    var defaultOptions = {
        templateName: '#button-tmpl',
        title: "Label goes here",
        type: "primary",
        size: "medium",
        disabled: null,
        autosave: null,
        href: null,
        onclick: null
    };
//debugger
//this.setOptions is not available here
    this.setOptions(options, defaultOptions);
    this.checkRequiredKeys('title');
    return this;
};
Button.prototype = new AbstractComponent;
```